# How can I disable the switch back to mpm_prefork by Apache Security update?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2-module

my Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 runs mpm_event, but on every Security Update Apache switch back to mpm_prefork. Why and how can I disable this, so mpm_event is still configured?

I found this: https://ubuntu101.co.za/apache-web-server/fix-apache-2-4-loading-wrong-mpm-worker-module/

But this don't work for me. After a security update I get the error message: "No MPM is configured". So my Apache don't run.

Did you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. However, I found that if I commented out the lines as described in https://ubuntu101.co.za/apache-web-server/fix-apache-2-4-loading-wrong-mpm-worker-module/ but then also added the line below underneath the commented-out lines in each file, mpm_prefork was disabled when updating. This worked for me on both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

`LoadModule mpm_event_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_event.so`

Doing this generated warnings about `php-fpm` and `proxy_fcgi` not being enabled but checking showed that they were actually still enabled.